# If a lot of vectors from vector space is eliminated, is it possible for remaining nonempty set to remain a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Well, I think it can because that way we would get some sort of vector subspace and by definition vector subspace is indeed a vector space. Even if we would eliminate all the vectors we would still get a trivial vector space.

Q:How do I prove it?

Comment: That really depends on what you mean by alot

Comment: Well, as my question clearly indicates, remaining vector space is not empty, so, we can eliminate all but 1 vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain conditions that must remain, for instance, you cannot remove the additive identity element $0$, since without it we would no longer have a vector space.

But for instance on any general vector space if we remove all elements except $0$ we are okay.

Answer (score 0):

The set $$\{(x,0)| x\in\mathbb R\}$$
is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ (obtained by "eliminating" vectors from $\mathbb R^2$ if you want to call it that) and is a vector space (it is a *subspace* of $\mathbb R^2$).

Comment: even just having the set $\{(0,0,0)\}$ will constitute a subspace, and that is removing all but one element.